# Ionic Capacitor Android build issue - Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crashlytics-android, capacitor

I had an old Ionic 3 project (with Cordova) and I started writing and developing it from scratch in Ionic 5 (With capacitor).

I have the following plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-androidx (1.0.2)
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter (1.1.0)
cordova-plugin-camera (4.1.0)
cordova-plugin-device (2.0.3)
cordova-plugin-firebasex (9.0.1)
cordova-plugin-printer (0.8.0)
```

I successfully followed the full workaround that Capacitor has in the documentation, running the necessary commands in order to create the Android project. I opened the project with Android studio. Here's a brief of the modules (they are all updated with the latest):

[image]

The issue appears when I'm trying to build the signed APK file. The error I get is the following:

> Execution failed for task '**:capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug**'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

Additional message is saying:

> Crashlytics could not find the manifest. Not found at **...\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml**

I mention that I have the Firebase Crashlytics turned on in the Firebase Console.

Any help with these?

Comment: Do you have the AndroidManifest.xml file in your project? Is the path correct?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Crashlytics in your project then you will have to comment out the `apply plugin: com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin` 
and 
`crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
    }` from `cordova-plugin-firebasex` android build.gradle file
[image]